# Symfony2 Making a Container-Aware Event Dispatcher

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I want to set an HTTP Request on the kernel in my Symfony2 application when a custom event is triggered (similar to how `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent` sets an HTTP Response on the kernel).

I followed the [Event Listeners cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/event_listener.html#creating-an-event-listener) and I build a Request, but my custom event doesn't have access to the kernel to pass the Request to. Further reading suggests I need a container aware event dispatcher and there is a [quick guide here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/event_dispatcher/container_aware_dispatcher.html).

Under setup the guide says "Setup is straightforward by injecting a ContainerInterface into the ContainerAwareEventDispatcher".

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher;

$container = new ContainerBuilder();
$dispatcher = new ContainerAwareEventDispatcher($container);
```

Where does that code go in my app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixed up, because you are trying to apply instructions, that are for the naked Event Dispatcher component.

Simply inject container in your event listener service:

```
my_listener:
    calls:
        - [setContainer, [@service_container]]
```

Comment: Thank you brother, I wasn't aware of setter injection. I added a `setContainer($container)` method on my event listener service and your definition to my services.yml and it works great